# checking html/css attribute value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am developing web site using jQuery and other tech. I have problem in selector as below.

My page contains a div with `id='tblData'`.
Inside `#tblData` I have created multiple tables with `class='data'`.

Inside a table (`.data`), i have created multiple tr and td. Some of these td have `class='vis'`.

I am changing display property of these `td.vis` dynamically from `block` to `none` as per my requirement.

When page loads I want to loop through all elements. My condition is that I want to loop through all `td`'s inside table (with `class='data'`) whose `display` property is not `none`.

I am writing following code but it doesn't work.

```
$("div#tblData .data td[class='vis']").each(function (i) {  
    if ($(this).attr('display') != "none") {
        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            $(this).removeClass("comparecontent2").removeClass("comparecontent1").addClass("comparecontent2");  
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("comparecontent2").removeClass("comparecontent1").addClass("comparecontent1"); 
        }
    }
});  

alert($("div#tblData .data td[class='vis']").size()); // shows zero while 'alert($("div#tblData .data td").size())';
                                                      // returns right count.
```

Comment: Tds should not be set to display block

Comment: initially td's display property is not set and later its changes to none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of those two commands:

```
.is(":hidden")
.filter(":hidden")
```

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

e.g.

```
  $(this).is(":hidden")
```

or

```
  $("td:hidden")
```

Comment: You're missing the colon on the selector in the `is` example. The way you have it, it's looking to see if it's a `hidden` element (e.g., like checking if it's a `div` element). *Edit:* Ah, you've fixed it now.

Comment: Yeah I just came out of my bed ;)

Answer (score 1):

"display" isn't an attribute, it's a style property. You could use `this.style.display`, but you may want jQuery's [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) instead. Note that the `:visible` selector checks things other than just the `display` style property, but they're mostly things you probably want to check. Has more overhead, but unless you're in a really tight loop that probably doesn't matter.

So either:

```
if (this.style.display != "none")
```

Or:

```
if ($(this).is(':visible'))
```